# Automapper 11, string to Uri no longer works

Tags: c#, automapper

since upgrading to automapper 11 trying to map a `string` to an `Uri` no longer works

Entity

```
public sealed class Website
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
}
```

object I'm mapping to

```
public sealed class WebsiteDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri BaseAddress { get; set; }
}
```

mapping profile contains

```
CreateMap<Website, WebsiteDto>();
```

and how I'm calling it

```
_mapper.Map<List<WebsiteDto>>(listOfWebsiteEntities);
```

This was working fine before upgrading to 11, I think it might be a bug but before I raise it as an issue Automapper suggests raising a question here, am I missing something?

after downgrading to automapper `10.1.1` it works again. the upgrade guide doesn't seem to mention anything related to this

Comment: Even with the currently accepted answer, did you verify that this solves the problem? I ask because constructing a simple program using AutoMapper 11, with your examples, allowed me to convert from Website to WebsiteDto, no errors, no missing data.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I assumed it's just no longer supported and changed my entity to be `Uri`, even though the accepted answer isn't what I decided to go with I think it will still help other people the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue affects only relative uris and happens due to the [next breaking change](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#system-componentmodel-typeconverter-is-no-longer-supported) in 11 version:

> `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter` is no longer supported
> It was removed for performance reasons. So it’s best not to use it anymore. But if you must, there is a [sample](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/ad5a6f84bdeec91af12a3f9e6947ad404ca54530/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L14) in the test project.

You can add `TypeConverterMapper` to mappers so `Automapper` will behave as previously. Note that this implementation is very primitive and very unperformant:

```cs
var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.Internal().Mappers.Insert(0, new TypeConverterMapper()))

public class TypeConverterMapper : ObjectMapper<object, object>
{
    public override bool IsMatch(TypePair context)
    {
        return GetConverter(context.SourceType).CanConvertTo(context.DestinationType) ||
            GetConverter(context.DestinationType).CanConvertFrom(context.SourceType);
    }

    public override object Map(object source, object destination, Type sourceType, Type destinationType, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var typeConverter = GetConverter(sourceType);
        return typeConverter.CanConvertTo(destinationType) ? typeConverter.ConvertTo(source, destinationType) : GetConverter(destinationType).ConvertFrom(source);
    }
    private TypeConverter GetConverter(Type type) => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
}
```

Or create a mapping from string to `Uri` which, I would say, is much better option. Quick and dirty one simulating behaviour of previous one can look like this:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<string, Uri>().ConvertUsing(s => (Uri)new UriTypeConverter().ConvertFrom(s));
```

Or just:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<string, Uri>().ConvertUsing(s => new Uri(s, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

[Related github issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3842)

Comment: But, _really_, just create the map. That mapper is gone for good reasons.

Comment: Hm, a simple test allowed me to convert from Website to WebsiteDto, are you sure this is the reason?

Comment: That works with `new Uri(string)`, but the type converter does smth else.

Comment: I think the main problem here is this part of the question: "no longer works". Since I got the code in the question to work as-is, I am just wondering what the actual problem was.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the issue is with relative uris. Previous version supported them while new one does not. See

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu `new Uri(string)` will fail for relative uri strings.

Comment: Perhaps this information ought to go in the question or this answer, or preferably both.

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen added to the answer.

Comment: This library is becoming more useless with every new version to the point that EVERY line of code in V10 is breaking. Lucian Bargaoanu seems unable to do anything unless you make a gist. Sooner or later we will all have to bin this library. So we decided to do it now. BIN IT!